# Can't get event fired (arrayChange)

Tags: jsviews

Can't get Sortable+arrayChange to work at all,

An exact example for Sortable+arrayChangethere:

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/ethar1/a2k0vbqj/]
```

Could you please help me to find out why?

[BorisMoore](https://github.com/BorisMoore), Thanks for your great efforts..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen to arrayChanges on the array, `model.items` not on the model.

```
$([model.items]).on("arrayChange", changeHandler);
```

See:

https://jsfiddle.net/r3vce9yz/

https://www.jsviews.com/#onarrchange@jquery-on

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what if I have multiple nested array?

Comment: Take a look at the docs for ObserveAll or for "**": https://www.jsviews.com/#observe@all-phones https://www.jsviews.com/#observeAll https://www.jsviews.com/#observe@all

Comment: Dear BorisMoor , unfortunately I failed to implement onchange could you please help!

https://jsfiddle.net/ethar1/Luwpe1v9/

Comment: That jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ethar1/Luwpe1v9/ makes no sense to me. It does not even have any html content!